# How can I get previous value of a variable correctly?

Tags: java, calendar

I want to get previous value of variable (gmtHourPrev), so I do as following. After change time for testing purpose, I saw the value of gmtHourPrev always equal gmtHour and can't get previous value of it. What am I doing wrong here ? Thanks

```
private int gmtHour;
private int gmtHourPrev;

public int getHour() {
    return gmtHour;
}    
public void setGmtHour(int gHour) {
    this.gmtHourPrev = this.gmtHour;
    this.gmtHour = gHour;
}    
public int getGmtHourPrev() {
    return gmtHourPrev;
}

public String getGmtHourInfo() {
    gmtHour = Calendar.HOUR;
    setGmtHour(gmtHour);
    if (isOK() == true) {
       return gmtHour;
    }
    else {
       return getGmtHourPrev();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Calendar.HOUR` is a constant, it isn't what you want. I don't understand what `getGmtHourInfo` is trying to do so I cannot suggest how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:

```
gmtHour = Calendar.HOUR;
setGmtHour(gmtHour);
```

Aside from the fact that `Calendar.HOUR` *probably* isn't what you think it is (that's a constant) you're effectively setting the variable twice. The above code is equivalent to:

```
gmtHour = Calendar.HOUR;
gmtHourPrev = gmtHour;
gmtHour = gmtHour;
```

That's equivalent to:

```
gmtHour = Calendar.HOUR;
gmtHourPrev = Calendar.HOUR;
```

You need to only set it once, e.g. *just* calling

```
setGmtHour(Calendar.HOUR);
```

Again though, that value almost certainly isn't what you want it to be...

You probably want:

```
setGmtHour(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
```

for some instance of `Calendar`.

Oh, and trying to return an `int` from a method declared to return `String` isn't a great idea either...

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.HOUR` is a static final int (a constant) that simply refers to a field in a Calendar object. Its use is to be passed to the `get()` method when being called on a Calendar instance to retrieve the hour value that Calendar represents.

That aside, these two lines:

```
gmtHour = Calendar.HOUR;
setGmtHour(gmtHour);
```

essentially mean that `gmtHour` and `gmtHourPrev` will always be equal, because you set `gmtHour` equal to the value, then call `setGmtHour()` which sets `gmtHourPrev` to the value of `gmtHour`, then sets `gmtHour` to the value passed (the current value of `gmtHour`).

Answer (score 0):

It works fine; I added some test code; see for yourself:

```
public class Main {
    private int gmtHour;
    private int gmtHourPrev
    public int getHour() {
        return gmtHour;
    }    
    public void setGmtHour(int gHour) {
        this.gmtHourPrev = this.gmtHour;
        this.gmtHour = gHour;
    }    
    public int getGmtHourPrev() {
        return gmtHourPrev;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setGmtHour(5);
        System.out.println("hour set to 5");
        System.out.println("getGmtHourPrev(): " + main.getGmtHourPrev());
        System.out.println("getHour(): " + main.getHour());
        main.setGmtHour(6);
        System.out.println("hour set to 6");
        System.out.println("getGmtHourPrev(): " + main.getGmtHourPrev());
        System.out.println("getHour(): " + main.getHour());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you are using one value to assign to `gmtHour` so you're always going to get one value.

```
public String getGmtHourInfo() {
    gmtHour = Calendar.HOUR;
    setGmtHour(gmtHour);
    ....
}
```

Your code will work if you use it like:

```
    setGmtHour(Calender.HOUR+1);
    setGmtHour(Calendre.HOUR);
    ....
```

and then print values you would see the difference.